# eclipse - shortcut for surrounding a String by double quotes

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

Does anyone else is annoyed by putting strings into double quotes manually ? If I'm not writing code from left to right, but pasting Strings (which happens very often), especially if double click selects the content between surrounding double quotes, I must go at the beginning, type ", then at the end and type " again...very annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if such a shortcut exists. But what you want seems doable using a macro. So I would:

- install [Practically Macro](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/practically-macro) for Eclipse
- record a macro doing something like <kbd>"</kbd> - <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> - <kbd>"</kbd> and name it
- go to the **Preferences**, then **General > Keys**, type the name of the macro and assign a shortcut.

Comment: It works great Pascal,  macro:  insert "; ctrl >; insert "  .... I put it as ctrl + z  and I have what I wanted